# Azure AAD app roles in v2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Are app roles supported in the V2 endpoint for Azure AAD apps?

I couldn't find an option for specifying aad app roles on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. Updating the manifest to add appRoles section also doesn't seem to work. Is that something that is going to be supported soon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-protocols

> > The v2.0 endpoint does not support issuing role or group claims in ID tokens.

So currently Azure AD V2.0 doesn't support app roles and there is no place in portal to assign roles to user/group . You could request this feature by sending feedback to [Azure Active Directory Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .